# Mediawiki Stylesheet Error

Tags: php, nginx, mediawiki, mediawiki-installation

I have a Problem with my mediawiki installation. Some sites are not loading properly. I already read error posts for many hours but couln't find a solution for me.
Most sites work fine:

[Main Page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JawPU.png)

[Version Page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vLkST.png)

At the "edit" site formatting breaks:
[Edit Page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NV46k.png)

I got following errors:
[Warning](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MGTq1.png)
[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VxfhG.png)

Warning Translation: Loading failed with Script for Source ....

Warning and Error appear on all sites.

URL/load.php gives me this:

```
/* This file is the Web entry point for MediaWiki's ResourceLoader:
   <https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/ResourceLoader>. In this request,
   no modules were requested. Max made me put this here. */
```

LocalSettings.php:

```
<?php
if ( !defined( 'MEDIAWIKI' ) ) {
    exit;
}

$wgSitename = "Some_Name";
$wgScriptPath = "";
$wgServer = "http://wiki.intern.zz";
$wgResourceBasePath = $wgScriptPath;
$wgLogo = "$wgResourceBasePath/resources/assets/wiki.png";
$wgEnableEmail = false;
$wgEnableUserEmail = true; # UPO
$wgEmergencyContact = "apache@wiki.intern.zz";
$wgPasswordSender = "apache@wiki.intern.zz";
$wgEnotifUserTalk = false; # UPO
$wgEnotifWatchlist = false; # UPO
$wgEmailAuthentication = true;
$wgDBtype = "mysql";
$wgDBserver = "localhost";
$wgDBname = "wikidb";
$wgDBuser = "wikiuser";
$wgDBpassword = "7YdLrbOCrtXnOS2FFGzF";
$wgDBprefix = "";
$wgDBTableOptions = "ENGINE=InnoDB, DEFAULT CHARSET=binary";
$wgDBmysql5 = false;
$wgMainCacheType = CACHE_ACCEL;
$wgMemCachedServers = [];
$wgEnableUploads = true;
$wgUseImageMagick = true;
$wgImageMagickConvertCommand = "/usr/bin/convert";
$wgUseInstantCommons = false;
$wgPingback = false;
$wgShellLocale = "en_US.utf8";
#$wgCacheDirectory = "$IP/cache";
$wgLanguageCode = "de";
$wgSecretKey="46c344c2c3d7af5f4210a0ead3f30002075087328e91aeece74cd086f22bbbb6";
$wgAuthenticationTokenVersion = "1";
$wgUpgradeKey = "d585d23ed115e0bd";
$wgRightsPage = ""; 
$wgRightsUrl = "";
$wgRightsText = "";
$wgRightsIcon = "";
$wgDiff3 = "/usr/bin/diff3";
$wgDefaultSkin = "vector";
wfLoadSkin( 'CologneBlue' );
wfLoadSkin( 'Modern' );
wfLoadSkin( 'MonoBook' );
wfLoadSkin( 'Vector' );

$wgShowExceptionDetails = TRUE;
```

nginx.conf:

```
        server{
                listen 80;
                root /data/www/mediawiki;
                index index.php
                server_name wiki.intern.zz;


        location ~ \.php$ {
                fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
                fastcgi_index index.php;
                include fastcgi.conf;
                include fastcgi_params;
        }
        }
}
```

Cache is always cleared.

OS is Alpine Linux with Nginx and php-fpm.

/tmp folder is writable.

There are NO rewrites set in Nginx.

Used Version is 1.30.0. Same Error with English and 1.29.2

If you need any additional Info please ask. Thank you

Comment: I am sure there must be a German site where people could understand your errors and other pictures

Comment: translated the warning which should be the only important thing.

Comment: You could add `&debug=true` to the Url to get uncompressed versions of your resources, that might help to pinpoint down where the bug is. Looks like you are trying to load a broken module